# How can I ignore certain referenced files or skip checks in tsconfig?

Tags: typescript

I have some files automatically generated from GRPC proto files. Unfortunately they have a if check typescript disagrees with:

> This condition will always return 'true' since the types
> 'Constructor' and '{ default: LongConstructor; prototype: Long;
> MAX_UNSIGNED_VALUE: Long; MAX_VALUE: Long; MIN_VALUE: Long; NEG_ONE:
> Long; ONE: Long; ... 11 more ...; fromValue(val: string | ... 2 more
> ... | { ...; }): Long; }' have no overlap

I don't want to have to manually go and add `// @tsignore` at the top of every file. Unfortunately adding the files to tsconfig.json's ignore array does not work as the file is referenced by other files. As per github, this means the files ARE checked and compiled always. I just want to be able to check and compile the rest of my project but ignore these certain files.